# Import c++ unmanaged dll to c# problem

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

i have this code in c++

```
   extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) void ConvertToByte(char *filename,unsigned char* data)

  {
       BITMAPINFO *info;
      data=(unsigned char *)LoadDIBitmap(filename, &info); 

  }
}
```

i want from c# to give the filename and take the data
how?

```
 [DllImport("bmpToByte.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern void ConvertToByte(string pame,ref byte[] data);
```

This way doesn't work.Any idea please help because i am new in programming and i have no idea how to do it.Thanks
I send all the code that i use from c++.Maybe someone has an idea.Please give some help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <windows.h>


void *
LoadDIBitmap(char       *filename, /* I - File to load */
             BITMAPINFO **info)    /* O - Bitmap information */
{
  FILE             *fp;            /* Open file pointer */
  void             *bits;          /* Bitmap pixel bits */
  long             bitsize,        /* Size of bitmap */
                   infosize;       /* Size of header information */
  BITMAPFILEHEADER header;         /* File header */

 /*
  * Try opening the file; use "rb" mode to read this *binary* file.
  */

  if ((fp = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL)
    return (NULL);

 /*
  * Read the file header and any following bitmap information…
  */

  if (fread(&header, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, fp) < 1)
  {
   /*
    * Couldn't read the file header - return NULL…
    */

    fclose(fp);
    return (NULL);
  };

  if (header.bfType != 'MB') /* Check for BM reversed… */
  {
   /*
    * Not a bitmap file - return NULL…
    */

    fclose(fp);
    return (NULL);
  };
  infosize = header.bfOffBits - sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER);
  if ((*info = (BITMAPINFO *)malloc(infosize)) == NULL)
  {
   /*
    * Couldn't allocate memory for bitmap info - return NULL…
    */

    fclose(fp);
    return (NULL);
  };

  if (fread(*info, 1, infosize, fp) < infosize)
  {
   /*
    * Couldn't read the bitmap header - return NULL…
    */

    free(*info);
    fclose(fp);
    return (NULL);
  };

 /*
  * Now that we have all the header info read in, allocate memory for the
  * bitmap and read *it* in…
  */

  if ((bitsize = (*info)->bmiHeader.biSizeImage) == 0)
    bitsize = ((*info)->bmiHeader.biWidth *
               (*info)->bmiHeader.biBitCount + 7) / 8 *
        abs((*info)->bmiHeader.biHeight);

  if ((bits = malloc(bitsize)) == NULL)
  {
   /*
    * Couldn't allocate memory - return NULL!
    */

    free(*info);
    fclose(fp);
    return (NULL);
  };

  if (fread(bits, 1, bitsize, fp) < bitsize)
  {
   /*
    * Couldn't read bitmap - free memory and return NULL!
    */

    free(*info);
    free(bits);
    fclose(fp);
    return (NULL);
  };

 /*
  * OK, everything went fine - return the allocated bitmap…
  */

  fclose(fp);
  return (bits);
}


int
SaveDIBitmap(char       *filename, /* I - File to save to */
             BITMAPINFO *info,     /* I - Bitmap information */
             void       *bits)     /* I - Bitmap pixel bits */
{
  FILE             *fp;            /* Open file pointer */
  long             size,           /* Size of file */
                   infosize,       /* Size of bitmap info */
                   bitsize;        /* Size of bitmap pixels */
  BITMAPFILEHEADER header;         /* File header */

 /*
  * Try opening the file; use "wb" mode to write this *binary* file.
  */

  if ((fp = fopen(filename, "wb")) == NULL)
    return (-1);

  if (info->bmiHeader.biSizeImage == 0)/* Figure out the bitmap size */
    bitsize = (info->bmiHeader.biWidth *
               info->bmiHeader.biBitCount + 7) / 8 *
      abs(info->bmiHeader.biHeight);
  else
    bitsize = info->bmiHeader.biSizeImage;

  infosize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
  switch (info->bmiHeader.biCompression)
  {
    case BI_BITFIELDS :
        infosize += 12; /* Add 3 RGB doubleword masks */
        if (info->bmiHeader.biClrUsed == 0)
          break;
    case BI_RGB :
        if (info->bmiHeader.biBitCount > 8 &&
            info->bmiHeader.biClrUsed == 0)
          break;
    case BI_RLE8 :
    case BI_RLE4 :
        if (info->bmiHeader.biClrUsed == 0)
          infosize += (1 << info->bmiHeader.biBitCount) * 4;
        else
          infosize += info->bmiHeader.biClrUsed * 4;
        break;
  };

  size = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + infosize + bitsize;

 /*
  * Write the file header, bitmap information, and bitmap pixel data…
  */

  header.bfType      = 'MB'; /* Non-portable… sigh */
  header.bfSize      = size;
  header.bfReserved1 = 0;
  header.bfReserved2 = 0;
  header.bfOffBits   = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + infosize;
  if (fwrite(&header, 1, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), fp) <
          sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER))
  {
   /*
    * Couldn't write the file header - return…
    */

    fclose(fp);
    return (-1);
  };
  int l;
  if (l=fwrite(info, 1, infosize, fp) < infosize)
  {
   /*
    * Couldn't write the bitmap header - return…
    */

    fclose(fp);
    return (-1);
  };

  if (l=fwrite(bits, 1, bitsize, fp) < bitsize)
  {
   /*
    * Couldn't write the bitmap - return…
    */

    fclose(fp);
    return (-1);
  };

 /*
  * OK, everything went fine - return…
  */

  fclose(fp);
  return (0);
}

extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) void ConvertToByte(char *filename,unsigned char** data)

  {
      char temp[100];
      sprintf(temp,filename);
       BITMAPINFO *info;
      *data=(unsigned char *)LoadDIBitmap(temp, &info); 


  }
```

Comment: I add the c++ code .Someone to help i have to give this project tommorow .

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
 [DllImport("bmpToByte.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, 
                             CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    unsafe static extern void ConvertToByte(string pame,byte* data);
```

Note the use of the [Cdecl calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx): without it, P/Invoke will assume the function uses the stdcall calling convention, and fail to clean up the stack. (You could also change the definition of your C function to include [`__stdcall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx))

Then you can pass the byte* with:

```
byte[] data = new byte[100000]
fixed (byte* p = data)
    {
        ConvertToByte(..., p);
    }
```

Unfortunately you have to ensure byte array is large enough :(

Comment: sorry I copied ypour prototype and miss to change with byte*. Try now ( look at the edited reply )

Comment: no it does not work .first i have a problem with the string i take in debugging PInvoke warning .And then the Data if i continue is not good

Comment: This one:A call to PInvoke function '@try!try.Form1::ConvertToByte' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.Thank you for helping.

Comment: i do not understand .i am new here

Comment: @kwstas: see my edit (Ramhound suggested this first, but his edit was rejected).

Comment: @Ramhound: for future reference, technical edits are generally looked at with a great deal of skepticism unless *strongly* justified. You could probably get away with posting a separate answer consisting of nothing but "try this code", but when editing an existing answer you should try to explain *why* the change is necessary (you kinda did, in your comment... but it was overlooked - try adding explanatory text to the answer itself next time). Alternately, post your correction in a comment so that it doesn't get lost.

Comment: @Felice: I have my doubts about this technique... The routine he's attempting to call appears to allocate its own memory internally rather than writing to a buffer that is provided. He really wants an `out` parameter for the data...

Comment: now i do not take the pinvoke warning but the Data is not good .I take wrong things.

Comment: @Shog9 The problem was as I suspected that the calling convention had to be declared as Cdecl and technically I am correct about that fact. In addition the fact he got data is a good thing, the fact its garbage data means the C++ code is wrong. My comment was justified, I just made the justification to the person who should have approved the comment, my suggestion was indeed valid. I saw an almost correct answer mission a single statement, I simply wanted the additional points, in the future take better care to read the justfication.  I saw no reason to explain the change within the post.

Comment: @Ramhound: I know your edit was correct - that's why I voted to approve it, and took the time to restore it after it was denied. I'm trying to explain why someone else may have voted to reject it - for more on this, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78845/should-suggested-edits-change-the-technical-content-of-a-post

Comment: the c++ code when i run it alone as a console application gives the result as must be.I try to find why i take wrong results when i use it as dll

Comment: @Shog9 - I figured since you said something it was you who rejected it.  I appreciate you voting to approve it.  I didn't realize it at the time.  I will let it go, however I am upset, that it was not approved just because everyone else in the queue cannot provide valid technical edits and provide clear justification for them.

Comment: @kwstas: passing arrays / block-allocated memory between C++ and .NET is actually harder than it looks. Even if you got your code working as it is, you'd be leaking memory left and right... I don't have time to give you a full answer right now, but I want you to stop and think carefully about where memory is being allocated, and where it is being written to: right now, you're losing track of memory that you allocate, and failing to write to the memory that you keep track of. You may wish to make some changes to LoadDIBitmap in order to simplify your task...

Comment: i can not find solution to my problem

Answer (score 1):

Just change `ref byte[] data` to `byte[] data` and I think it should work - the rest seems correct.

Comment: it does not work i.i call the function ConvertToByte(filename,Data); but the Data array an the end is empty.Why?

Answer (score 1):

The C++ code is no good: you're setting `data` which is a parameter in the `ConvertToByte` function.  It's not passed out.  You could use this as a starting point, for the C++ side at least:

```
extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) void ConvertToByte(char *filename,unsigned char** data)

  {
       BITMAPINFO *info;
       *data=(unsigned char *)LoadDIBitmap(filename, &info); 
  }
```

}

That way the caller passes in a pointer to a pointer.  The function puts the pointer to the image data, in that pointer.

Comment: It does not work because you would now have to send a pointer to a pointer which I suspect you are not doing based on the code you posted.  Most of time I would send a reference to a IntPtr in order to do that. Have you tried using my suggestion of the CallingConvention with YOUR posted code?